# No Site Url in Password Reset Email

Tags: forgot-password

EE 5.2.2
hosted on Digital Ocean provisioned by Forge

When requesting a password reset the email is recieved but the url is missing the domain and is not clickable.

```
To reset your password, please go to the following page:

?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&resetcode=PtwbN4zP
```

Default base URL is set correctly `https://domain.com/`

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the URL and path settings page check the setting 'Control panel directory
URL location of your control panel' as that controls the URL in the password reset email.

Setting it to something like {base_url}your-admin.php should do the trick

Comment: Thank you - didn't notice that that setting was empty.

Comment: No problem, I was curious so started knocking out the settings one by one on my test install until it borked the password reset email.